# codeIgniter Navigation Basics

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do you make a simple navigation in Code Igniter? I keep tripping up on all these pseudo folders. Originally I was looking to make something that dug through a folder and grabbed all the file-names, then placed them in an array to order them into a nav bar.

Problem is, it seems that CI uses public functions for the pseudo folder in each page. Such as "public function aboutme()" would work out to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php/[classname]/aboutme. This poses a problem for me, because when making links like [test](/contactme) works out to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/[classname]/contactme.

Is there a better, dynamic way to make a nav bar without using a database? I CAN use a database, but I'm trying to learn CI and since I'm already well-versed in MySQL I wanted to find a way to do this some other way.

Comment: *CodeIgniter* provides a pseudo path scheme for each page.  I found it convenient in developing my app as the paths I chose were *[verb]/[object]* such as `edit/selection` and `view/user`.  You are not obligated to use it.  You can easily redo or override that portion of CI.

Comment: Is there no way to get an array of classes and their respective paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a custom route would help you?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

I'm not sure the structure of your application, but if you are using multiple controllers, it won't really help and there isn't really an easy way to do it "automagically". The best thing would be to come up with some way to manage the navigation items, such as a database (as you said).

If you're only using one class, you can use PHP's `get_class_methods()` on the class.

```
$pages = get_class_methods('classname');

foreach($pages as $page)
{
    echo anchor($page, ucfirst($page));
}
```

This is a very simplistic way to do it, and you'll have to filter out private methods and the `__construct` method as well.

Comment: In this case, I have a header, body, and footer for each page. Each page is automatically generated by a public function defined in the class. I find it *a little* hard to believe that CI doesn't keep a cache of functions included in a class, along with each function's respective pseudo location - or if it doesn't keep record, that it doesn't know that multiple functions exist.

But I may be wrong, I've only been doing this for a day.

Comment: So, are you only using one class?

Comment: Class [classname] extends CI_Controller, Then various public functions that create pages. I haven't yet found a reason to make multiple classes, just multiple functions within the class.

Comment: If you're only using the one class, you can use `get_class_methods('classname')` and filter out the ones you don't want in the navigation by removing them from the array with `unset()` or `array_splice()` (depending on if you want to normalize the array indices).